# Stop listener from firing inside the same click EventListener without removing it

Tags: javascript

so, I need a form to stay displayed when it's clicked on the inside of a click event listener. The concept is, you open up the form by clicking on the button, then the form appears (this works). The form closes if you click anywhere on the page (this also works) but I need it to stay open if you click on the form. Currently, it disappears if I click on the form. Event tried "event.preventDefault()"

Any help would be appreciated

HTML

```
<button class="button">Click me</button>
<div class="form">
  This is a form
</div>
```

CSS

```
.form {
  display: none;
}
.form.show-form {
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
let searchToggle = document.querySelector('.button');
let searchForm = document.querySelector('.form');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let toggled = searchToggle.contains(event.target);
  if (toggled) {
    searchForm.classList.add('show-form');
    if (event.searchForm === toggled) {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    searchForm.classList.remove('show-form');
  }
});
```

**Update #1: @trincot's Solution**

```
let searchToggle = document.querySelector('.button');
let searchForm = document.querySelector('.form');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let toggled = searchToggle.contains(event.target);
  if (toggled) {
    searchForm.classList.add('show-form');
  } else if (!event.target.closest('.show-form')) {
    searchForm.classList.remove('show-form');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is an element that has the form as ancestor or is the form itself (using [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)):

```
  } else if (!event.target.closest(".show-form")) {
    searchForm.classList.remove('show-form');
  }
```

Comment: `currentTarget` is always the event to which the listener was attached (in this case the document). You're thinking of `target`. Yes, I also think it should be the other way around.

Comment: @trincot This works perfectly, thank you. Uses less code and easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Just add in `if(event.target == searchForm) return` on the first line of your event listener.

snippet below

```js
let searchToggle = document.querySelector('.button');
let searchForm = document.querySelector('.form');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target == searchForm) return
  let toggled = searchToggle.contains(event.target);
  if (toggled) {
    searchForm.classList.add('show-form');
    if (event.searchForm === toggled) {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    searchForm.classList.remove('show-form');
  }
});
```

```css
.form {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.form.show-form {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Click me</button>
<div class="form">
  This is a form
</div>
```

Comment: This also works well. Seemed I missed using an "early return", again (had sort of a similar issue in a past post). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a form overlay,and attach a click event listener to the overlay.

```
<div id="overlay" style="width="100vw; height:100vh; position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px" >
   <form> </form>
</div>
```

And add attach event listener to the overlay.

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("click",event=>{
     event.target.style.display = "none";
 });
</script>
```

Comment: This may come in handy, been seeing a lot of search overlays on blogs lately. Cheers!